# Cloudflare bypass python

Tags: python, screen-scraping, cloudflare

I'm trying to parse a site with cloudflare protection.
On most cloudflare sites I've worked with, it would be sufficient to extract the cf_clearance cookie from the browser and paste it into the request headers.

But in my case ( northerntool.com ) I cannot send any successful request. I only get a 403 response. Although I copy the request completely from the browser along with the headers and cookies.

Anyone can helps me?

```
import requests

proxies = { # my browser uses same proxies
    'http': 'socks5://51.75.159.197:10414',
    'https': 'socks5://51.75.159.197:10414'
}

cookies = {
    '_cfuvid': 'bO9YJsGcxkn.HngvuOuQgZxpINGtbO_pqWLVrfmTykE-1678639824166-0-604800000',
    'BVBRANDID': '0815b8e6-64c7-45cf-b643-8a705351ed19',
    'BVBRANDSID': '747df48b-b84f-4093-84cd-2c944b41cc48',
    'page_site_section': 'cart',
    'at_check': 'true',
    '__ogfpid': '1239f1df-419c-43f8-92f6-7b9633b52767',
    '__cf_bm': 's.ZHBJo_3wGNwhZmtxVyZBgNq6v4IC6vLfkOnR78Rhc-1678639827-0-ATKGlsFBMrDubyu0vPBqM2Rg7KYz/EmpbCb8YxSuwwZakke2dDjRap74BUxujLtcwx+vM7GdpyCBEClecuWABOQcLug0XKWzGZwDatdn8+dG15IC0tRiB0Dq4qVT3Ure0zkrtD5DXFz7kpyBuVcpxs18jfgG+zZ8XSqkJj4pXYEkv1OG5MToHSGilvJHsBsbSA==',
    '__cfruid': '1dda80a088bc9e474d44593545679c0f23c67c71-1678639827',
    'AMCVS_C1D7337B54F62DE60A4C98A1%40AdobeOrg': '1',
    'AMCV_C1D7337B54F62DE60A4C98A1%40AdobeOrg': '-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C19429%7CMCMID%7C42449510739611387111063046880270933266%7CMCAAMLH-1679244628%7C9%7CMCAAMB-1679244628%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1678647028s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.2.0',
    's_cc': 'true',
    '_gcl_au': '1.1.21290319.1678639829',
    'ftr_blst_1h': '1678639829167',
    '_fbp': 'fb.1.1678639829287.1170115554',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.627376372.1678639829',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1957429672.1678639829',
    'lo-uid': 'bb203c7c-1678639828816-fabce0f79a1a8dde',
    'lo-visits': '59',
    'sp': '7769f140-c2ca-49ca-b7aa-b9e99f5d9c9e',
    '_pin_unauth': 'dWlkPU9EVTBZMlE1T0RJdE5qVmlZeTAwWlRnMExXSmlPV1l0TTJReU1XWXlPRFk0T1RFeA',
    'xyz_cr_896_et_100': '=NaN&cr=896&et=100',
    'BE_CLA3': 'p_id%3DP4J282JP42L4RP4JP2862LRP8AAAAAAAAH%26bf%3D15bd409b13ac1783a03fcd0cd1e9d248%26bn%3D3%26bv%3D3.45%26s_expire%3D1678726441820%26s_id%3DP4J282JP42L4R68L84R62LRP8AAAAAAAAH',
    'utag_main': 'v_id:0186d6bb094700036007f383133c0506e002106600bd0$_sn:1$_se:5$_ss:0$_st:1678641848619$ses_id:1678639827272%3Bexp-session$_pn:5%3Bexp-session$vapi_domain:northerntool.com$customer_id:%3Bexp-session',
    'mbox': 'session#042409706d134fcca40c810a6c633fd0#1678641910|PC#042409706d134fcca40c810a6c633fd0.37_0#1741884850',
    '_uetsid': 'fe9f2b00c0f511eda0e601fdfe0b93fe',
    '_uetvid': 'fe9f33e0c0f511ed85105fd153c101de',
    'mp_northern_tool_mixpanel': 'eyJkaXN0aW5jdF9pZCI6ICIxODZkNmJiMTE5MDViZS0wNjM5ZGFiNzU5NjMxMi04MTA2ZjJjLTFmYTQwMC0xODZkNmJiMTE5MWNhYiIsImJjX3BlcnNpc3RfdXBkYXRlZCI6IDE2Nzg2Mzk4MjkzOTR9',
    'forterToken': '366913d6879248e7ae1997f60f1cf581_1678640047259__UDF43_11ck',
    'JSESSIONID': '00009dMsP0xzLMWob9c3lc4Ogww:-1',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.northerntool.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    # 'cookie': '_cfuvid=bO9YJsGcxkn.HngvuOuQgZxpINGtbO_pqWLVrfmTykE-1678639824166-0-604800000; BVBRANDID=0815b8e6-64c7-45cf-b643-8a705351ed19; BVBRANDSID=747df48b-b84f-4093-84cd-2c944b41cc48; page_site_section=cart; at_check=true; __ogfpid=1239f1df-419c-43f8-92f6-7b9633b52767; __cf_bm=s.ZHBJo_3wGNwhZmtxVyZBgNq6v4IC6vLfkOnR78Rhc-1678639827-0-ATKGlsFBMrDubyu0vPBqM2Rg7KYz/EmpbCb8YxSuwwZakke2dDjRap74BUxujLtcwx+vM7GdpyCBEClecuWABOQcLug0XKWzGZwDatdn8+dG15IC0tRiB0Dq4qVT3Ure0zkrtD5DXFz7kpyBuVcpxs18jfgG+zZ8XSqkJj4pXYEkv1OG5MToHSGilvJHsBsbSA==; __cfruid=1dda80a088bc9e474d44593545679c0f23c67c71-1678639827; AMCVS_C1D7337B54F62DE60A4C98A1%40AdobeOrg=1; AMCV_C1D7337B54F62DE60A4C98A1%40AdobeOrg=-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C19429%7CMCMID%7C42449510739611387111063046880270933266%7CMCAAMLH-1679244628%7C9%7CMCAAMB-1679244628%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1678647028s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.2.0; s_cc=true; _gcl_au=1.1.21290319.1678639829; ftr_blst_1h=1678639829167; _fbp=fb.1.1678639829287.1170115554; _ga=GA1.2.627376372.1678639829; _gid=GA1.2.1957429672.1678639829; lo-uid=bb203c7c-1678639828816-fabce0f79a1a8dde; lo-visits=59; sp=7769f140-c2ca-49ca-b7aa-b9e99f5d9c9e; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU9EVTBZMlE1T0RJdE5qVmlZeTAwWlRnMExXSmlPV1l0TTJReU1XWXlPRFk0T1RFeA; xyz_cr_896_et_100==NaN&cr=896&et=100; BE_CLA3=p_id%3DP4J282JP42L4RP4JP2862LRP8AAAAAAAAH%26bf%3D15bd409b13ac1783a03fcd0cd1e9d248%26bn%3D3%26bv%3D3.45%26s_expire%3D1678726441820%26s_id%3DP4J282JP42L4R68L84R62LRP8AAAAAAAAH; utag_main=v_id:0186d6bb094700036007f383133c0506e002106600bd0$_sn:1$_se:5$_ss:0$_st:1678641848619$ses_id:1678639827272%3Bexp-session$_pn:5%3Bexp-session$vapi_domain:northerntool.com$customer_id:%3Bexp-session; mbox=session#042409706d134fcca40c810a6c633fd0#1678641910|PC#042409706d134fcca40c810a6c633fd0.37_0#1741884850; _uetsid=fe9f2b00c0f511eda0e601fdfe0b93fe; _uetvid=fe9f33e0c0f511ed85105fd153c101de; mp_northern_tool_mixpanel=eyJkaXN0aW5jdF9pZCI6ICIxODZkNmJiMTE5MDViZS0wNjM5ZGFiNzU5NjMxMi04MTA2ZjJjLTFmYTQwMC0xODZkNmJiMTE5MWNhYiIsImJjX3BlcnNpc3RfdXBkYXRlZCI6IDE2Nzg2Mzk4MjkzOTR9; forterToken=366913d6879248e7ae1997f60f1cf581_1678640047259__UDF43_11ck; JSESSIONID=00009dMsP0xzLMWob9c3lc4Ogww:-1',
    'if-modified-since': 'Sat, 11 Mar 2023 04:07:21 GMT',
    'if-none-match': 'W/"3503-5f69803b20b49"',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'service-worker-navigation-preload': 'true',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.northerntool.com/cart', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
# 403 Just a moment...
pass
```

i also tried use httpx with http2 protocol. it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.
The problem was because of the 'accept' header. More specifically, the lack of spaces after commas. If you remove it, the site returns 200 code with the content.

Thanks to this guy: https://youtu.be/eA-NzVJ0Tsg?list=LL&t=345

The funny thing is that it took me 24 hours to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, Cloudflare will make Javascript requests to see if the browser is from "a real user":

[image]

You can try to use the `selenium` library to simulate a browser more realistically w/ Javascript:

```
from selenium                          import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Set the options for the Chromium browser
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Set the driver for the Chromium browser
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Navigate to your website and close browser
chrome_driver.get("http://www.google.com")
chrome_driver.quit()
```